# Crystal Report Fields Ungrouping

Tags: text, crystal-reports, formula

I am working with existing crystal report and at the moment I am totally helpless to un-group two fields added in Text object.

Basically I want to add formula to one of the embedded field and I can not select that, below is the image i am attaching , 
[image]

Here you can see two fields are embedded in a Text control, I wanted to select the Top (**Extra_Merch_Desc...**) field, Kindly help in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with different way.. No Hover and drop is there.Instead after adding formula, you Ctrl-X the desired field and double click the Text field then Paste in it.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed these steps to modify the fonts:

1. Select the required field(s)
2. From the Format menu select the Format Field option
3. Click on the Font Tab
4. Press the [x+2] button to the right of the Size drop down
5. Enter the following formula:

   IF Len({Customer.Customer Name})>15 Then 8 else

   IF Len({Customer.Customer Name}) in 10 to 15 Then 9 else 10
6. Press the Save and Close button

   [Reference Link](http://www.maximumimpactsolutions.co.uk/blog/comments.asp?bd=139)

I have double clicked the Text box and found two options :

- Text Formatting...
- Format Embedded Field...

When I do modify the Formula and "**Save & Close** Option Press" , it saves and I can see Formula in the Formula box, but after exiting from Formatting Box next time that formula disappears.

Below is the formula for the font change:

```
if Length({myfield}) < 50
   then 16
else if ((Length({myfield}) >= 50) AND   (Length({myfield}) < 80 ))
   then 13
else if ((Length({myfield}) >= 80) AND (Length({myfield}) < 100 ))
   then 11
else
        10
```